# UWP Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am creating a blank UWP using Visual Studio 2015

I am getting the following errors every time i try to build

```
Error   CS1061  'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Error       Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
```

[image]

I tried uninstalling the windows software developement kit then installing it with no luck

I had a working project but now it's giving the same error

The targets in the .csproj are as following

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Comment: what do you have in XAML? If nothing - try to clean solution and rebuild it with right-click in Solution Explorer

Comment: I tried cleaning and creating a new project nothing worked

Comment: what is path1? do you recognize it or is it just some junk from visual studio? it looks like there is something wrong with anything named path1, rest is just junk

Comment: Did you try to compile the app? I know it's a dumb question but I've experienced many similar "Errors" that were resolved just by compilation.

Comment: As I can see some references might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that namespace is correct in both file MainPage.xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml.

Example:-

[image: XAML]

[image: C#]

After cross check if same issue persist then delete obj and bin folder from the solution and then rebuilt solution again.